# R tidytext stop_words are not filtering consistently from gutenbergr downloads

Tags: r, stop-words, tidytext, anti-join

This is a bizarre puzzle. I downloaded 2 texts from gutenbergr - Alice in Wonderland and Ulysses.
The stop_words disappear from Alice but they are still in Ulysses.
This issue persisted even when replacing anti_join with 
filter (!word %in% stop_words$word).

How do I get the stop_words out of Ulysses?

Thanks for your help!

[Plot of top 15 tf_idf for Alice & Ulysses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fm003.jpg)

```
library(gutenbergr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidytext)
library(ggplot2)

titles <- c("Alice's Adventures in Wonderland", "Ulysses")


books <- gutenberg_works(title %in% titles) %>%
  gutenberg_download(meta_fields = c("title", "author"))


data(stop_words)


tidy_books <- books %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%
  anti_join(stop_words) %>%
  count(title, word, sort=TRUE) %>%
  ungroup()


plot_tidy_books <- tidy_books %>%
  bind_tf_idf(word, title, n) %>%
  arrange(desc(tf_idf))       %>%
  mutate(word = factor(word, levels = rev(unique(word)))) %>%
  mutate(title = factor(title, levels = unique(title)))


plot_tidy_books %>%
  group_by(title) %>%
  arrange(desc(n))%>%
  top_n(15, tf_idf) %>%
  mutate(word=reorder(word, tf_idf)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(word, tf_idf, fill=title)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  labs(x=NULL, y="tf-idf") +
  facet_wrap(~title, ncol=2, scales="free") +
  coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit of digging in the tokenized Ulysses, the text "it's" is actually using a right single quotation mark instead of an apostrophe.  `stop_words` in `tidytext` uses an apostrophe.  You have to replace the right single quotation with an apostrophe.

I found this out by:

```
> utf8ToInt('it’s')
[1]  105  116 8217  115
```

Googling the 8217 lead me to [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm).  From there it's as easy as grabbing the C++/Java source `\u2019` and adding a `mutate` and `gsub` statement prior to your `anti-join`.

```
tidy_books <- books %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%
  mutate(word = gsub("\u2019", "'", word)) %>% 
  anti_join(stop_words) %>%
  count(title, word, sort=TRUE) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Results in:

[image]

Comment: Those little quotes/apostrophes are so sneaky! Thank you for figuring this out and teaching me how to fix it.

Comment: If it helped, you can accept it as an answer so others will know.

Comment: Oh, ok - I am new here - will do!